# jQuery Plugin: Using setInterval to periodically update an array of jQuery elements

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin which introduces a new method `foo()`, which creates some `<img>` element within the DOM object it is called on. I store the pointers to these images in an array `images`. At the end of the method, I call `setInterval("someFunction(images)", 1000)` which should periodically perform some actions (e.g. change the `src`) on the images.

Here is a very short version of what my code looks like:

```
(function($) { 
$.fn.foo = function () {
return this.each (function () {
    $box = $("#"+this.id);

    images = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        images[i] = $("<img>");
        $box.prepend(images[i]);
    }

    setInterval("someFunction(images)", 1000);
});
}
function someFunction(images) {
    for (i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
        images[i].attr("src", "foo"+(parseInt(Math.random()*5)));
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Everything works if I apply `foo()` to a single element, but if I apply it to multiple elements, all the periodic updates are applied to the last element. I assume this is because the array is passed as a reference to `someFunction`, and is then overwritten.

I tried to use `slice()` on the array to create a copy, but that did not work, though I don't understand why. I think what I'm looking for is to somehow store the pointers to my images within their parent container.

Any help would be appreciated on what I need to change so that all the images are updated and not just the ones in the last container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this then:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foo = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $box = $(this); // Changed to "this"

            var images = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                images[i] = $("<img>");
                $box.prepend(images[i]);
            }

            // Added the function inline.
            setInterval(function () {
                for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].attr("src", "foo" + (parseInt(Math.random() * 5)));
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:

You could also try it like this if you want to reuse `someFunction`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foo = function () {
       ...
            setInterval(function () {
                someFunction(images);
            }, 1000);
       ...
    };
})(jQuery);

function someFunction(images) {
    for (i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
        images[i].attr("src", "foo"+(parseInt(Math.random()*5)));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `images` is declared inside (I forgot to write `var`), but that raises the problem that they are local to the function and no longer available to `someFunction`. On the other hand, if I declare them outside, they are overwritten. That is my problem.

Comment: I don't like the style of having it as an inline function, but it definitely works :D. Thanks for your help. A minor problem I'm having now is that I want the function to be called right at the beginning too (in addition to every second). How can I do that without copying the entire inline function?

Comment: I've updated the answer again, if I understood you correctly =)